# perl, DBI, MS SQL and prepared statements

Tags: sql-server, perl, dbi

I have Perl, DBI and the linux ODBC drivers on a RedHat box.  I am trying to connect to an MS SQL database.  I think the ODBC setup is correct.  I was about to ask a different question when I decided to make sure the connection was really working and just do a simple query.

```
...
my @connection_MSSQL = (
    "DBI:ODBC:DSN=msdb.my.company.com",
    'notARealUser',
    'notAPassword',
    {   PrintError => 0,
        RaiseError => 1,
        AutoCommit => 1
    }
);

my $MSdbh = DBI->connect_cached(@connection_MSSQL)
    or die __LINE__ . ": $<: " . DBI::errstr . "\n";

$MSdbh->trace(2);
my $msTest = $MSdbh->prepare('SELECT SYSDATETIME()');
$msTest->execute();
my $msTestVal = "";
$msTest->bind_col(1, \$msTestVal);
print STDERR "msTestVal=$msTestVal\n";
$MSdbh->trace(0);
...
```

with the `trace` result

```
DBI::db=HASH(0xf405818) trace level set to 0x0/2 (DBI @ 0x0/0) in DBI 1.634-ithread (pid 3974)
-> prepare for DBD::ODBC::db (DBI::db=HASH(0xf4058c0)~0xf405818 'SELECT SYSDATETIME()') thr#e7da010
<- prepare= ( DBI::st=HASH(0xf405bf0) ) [1 items] at script.pl line 133
-> execute for DBD::ODBC::st (DBI::st=HASH(0xf405bf0)~0xf405ba8) thr#e7da010
<- execute= ( -1 ) [1 items] at script.pl line 134
-> bind_col for DBD::ODBC::st (DBI::st=HASH(0xf405bf0)~0xf405ba8 1 SCALAR(0xf11ff88)) thr#e7da010
<- bind_col= ( 1 ) [1 items] at script.pl line 136
msTestVal=
-> trace in DBD::_::common for DBD::ODBC::db (DBI::db=HASH(0xf4058c0)~0xf405818 0) thr#e7da010
<- trace= ( 2 ) [1 items] at script.pl line 138
-> DESTROY for DBD::ODBC::st (DBI::st=HASH(0xf405ba8)~INNER) thr#e7da010
<- DESTROY= ( undef ) [1 items] at script.pl line 365
```

It seems like the connection is working... or not barfing.  It looks like the `prepare`, `execute` and `bind_col` all "work" but I'm not seeing a result bound into the result variable.

In this case I am asking for a system datetime value.  I have also tried selecting a static string value, a la: `SELECT 'asdf'` with the same result. No errors are reported.

Ideas?

Comment: Where `$msTest->fetch` after bind ?

Comment: DOH! I am a blind fool.  thank you